# Do wizards know of great literature by Muggles?

Tags: harry-potter

Inspired by [Does Hogwarts teach non magical classes](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7436/does-hogwarts-teach-non-magical-classes) question, as well as the Harry Potter series' supposed effect on children in introducing them to reading.

I'm curious whether there are mentions in the story / Word of God about wizards' knowledge of literature by authors known to Muggles. Like, say, Ron arguing with Neville about Nabokov, Hermione quoting 1984 at Umbridge, or Harry curling up with The Great Gatsby.  Or a professor saying something in class that acknowledges the existence of great real-life literature.  Or even JKR mentioning some specific Muggle book Dumbledore likes.  Anything like that.

Basically, is there any specific word by JKR in books or exchanges to suggest that wizards read something other than news and magic-world-related things?

Comment: Dumbledore likes reading muggle knitting magazines

Comment: A wizard in the films is reading "A Brief History of Time"

Comment: @Valorum I suppose that seems a little unsatisfying.  I guess I'm looking for mentions of *great literature* - i.e. creative fiction.  The reason I'm asking about that is because of the seeming lack of core English classes at Hogwarts, and the supposed encouragement that Harry Potter provides to children to start reading books.  I'll change the question to reflect that.

Comment: Possible answer here? https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/57097/what-do-wizards-read-for-fun

Comment: http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_books - There's lots of books seen in the films and almost none mentioned in the books

Comment: The discussion about books encouraging young people to read was interesting, but only tangentially relevant and getting a bit long; I've [moved it to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76425/discussion-on-question-by-misha-r-do-wizards-know-of-great-literature-by-muggles), where you can continue as long as you like.

Comment: To wizards, _A Brief History of Time_ might be considered creative fiction.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard Yes, but what I want are explicit mentions in the story or via discussion by JKR.  *A Brief History of Time* is just a movie cameo - passive permission by JKR, rather than deliberate mention.

Comment: You seem to assume that Nabokov, Orwell and Fitzgerald are Muggle...

Comment: Surely some of them must have gotten their hands on Trump's "Art of the Deal" by now.

Comment: Since they celebrate Easter and Christmas, I assume some of them have read the Bible

Comment: @ColonD, that doesn't follow.  In Britain, neither holiday is considered to be exclusive to Christians.

Comment: @HarryJohnston I never said it was exclusive. But anyone who celebrates Christmas will know about the historical origin of the holiday and thus  at least a few should have read the Bible

Comment: @ColonD, I don't see why you necessarily need to know about the history of a holiday in order to celebrate it.  But it's a moot point, we can be pretty sure that wizards are familiar with the Bible from the [inscriptions in the graveyard.](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/James_and_Lily_Potter%27s_grave)

Comment: @ColonD I think it would be very strange if anyone - wizard or otherwise - were not aware of a 2000 year old religious tradition responsible for the development of the entire Western culture. Can we avoid the technicalities and just agree that the Bible would make for kind of a crappy answer?

Comment: @Harry Johnston I'm simply providing an answer to the question and simply listed one of the facts backing it. I never said It was the only fact backing it. As for whether It's a crappy answer, It's the only book that has extensive references in canon, so I stated it, and why I didn't post it as an answer.

Comment: @ColonD, I think Misha's point is not that your original comment was inappropriate but that there's no need to continue to argue about it.  I think that's even more true given that I've already conceded that my original objection was irrelevant.  That was my fault, and I apologize.  I had quite simply forgotten that there were direct Biblical references in Harry Potter, and you'd be surprised [how many people don't understand that Christmas is not exclusively Christian](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/121441/5930).

Comment: @HarryJohnston Well put.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

## Some do, at least.

In “The Tales of Beedle the Bard”, Dumbledore quotes the Muggle poet Alexander Pope.

> “We may smile, a little sadly, at what this tells us about human nature. The kindest interpretation would be: “Hope springs eternal.”<sup>21</sup>”

In the corresponding note, J.K. Rowling says that Dumbledore was familiar with the writings of this poet as well as being well-read in the wizarding world, and this implies it’s an intentional quote.

> “<sup>21</sup> [This quotation demonstrates that Albus Dumbledore was not only exceptionally well-read in Wizarding terms, but also that he was familiar with the writings of Muggle poet Alexander Pope. — JKR]” 
> <sub><sup>*- The Tales of Beedle the Bard*</sup></sub>

Dumbledore was pro-Muggle and was a bit of a philomath in general, so it’s unclear exactly how common it is for wizards to read Muggle literature, but it’s possible even for someone who grew up entirely in the wizarding world to have read some Muggle literature as well.

Comment: Dumbledore: an unbelievably lonely man surrounded by fanatics and fireworks.

Comment: Presumably Hermione Granger does too. And Harry might know some though even if he was inclined to being a bookworm he had a harsher upbringing. But your last point is also valid. He was after all pro-Muggle. Look at the way the Malfoy clan viewed Muggle ideas. Contempt at best. And although they were extremists (although Draco rather tried to break away from that some he still was obviously affected by his parents being that way and so not perfect) many were still contemptuous of Muggles.

Comment: @Pryftan Hermione almost certainly would have - she was raised by Muggles, and so was Harry. Dumbledore having read Muggle literature shows that even someone who grew up in the wizarding world could find and read Muggle literature. Yes, I strongly suspect Dumbledore was willing to read it since he was pro-Muggle. I highly doubt that someone like Lucius Malfoy would bother with it. Noble pure-bloods would never read that Muggle filth! ;)

Comment: I don't know how familiar you'd need to be with Pope in order to quote the literally most famous sentence he ever wrote

Comment: @Valorum Quoting something he hasn't read feels very out of character for Dumbledore.

Comment: Which leads us to the great question... live with magical powers, or live with Brandon Sanderson novels?

Comment: @MishaR - Everyone in the English-speaking world quotes Shakespeare multiple times every day but only a fraction are aware that these commonplace clichés are part of a wider work.

Comment: @Valorum Yes, but A. we aren't taking about Shakespeare. We're talking about Alexander Pope, and B. I'm pretty sure Dumbledore would belong to that fraction.

Comment: The irony though wrt Muggle filth is you could say HP is the *the work of a Muggle!* But you’re right; look at the commentary Dumbledore has in Beedle including references to Malfoy attempts of sabotaging pro Muggle stories like the Hopping Pot (or whatever it was) or maybe also the one about the fountain? Anyway love your RPing so keep it up! And yes you do well RPing Miss Bella! I enjoy it a lot and it’s fun to RP along with you. But as for Harry yes but he was restricted and neglected so not as likely even if he was a bookworm. That’s what I was trying to say.

Comment: @Pryftan Well yes, but once we’re out of universe, *everything* is Muggle-written! Yes, Lucius Malfoy tried very hard to ban “The Fountain of Fair Fortune” because it showed a wizard/Muggle marriage. “The Wizard and the Hopping Pot” was also controversial for its moral of helping Muggles, and anti-Muggle wizards tell a rewritten version. Many pure-bloods, including Lucius’s ancestor Brutus, disapproved of fraternizing with Muggles. Thanks, I’m glad you enjoy it! :) I agree, because of the Dursleys’ treatment of him Harry would likely only be able to read whatever books were assigned in school.

Comment: I must be a philomath, because I enjoyed learning what *philomath* means. :)

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd Awesome, I am too - I like learning new words and sometimes using them in answers! :)

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd I used to read the dictionary as if it was a novel. In fact if I am not extremely careful when I am looking up a word I will find myself reading lexicographically close words (or words the original definition used and then the same trap). Suddenly I've neglected the reason I wanted to look the word up in the first place! I love words. Words are truly magic. Without words what would we have ? I think I know the answer but I ... :)

Comment: @Bellatrix That is true yes. Unless of course we're talking about computer generated stories (though that's indirectly Muggle). Yes those are the stories I was referring to and more specifically the actual bias against Muggles. I seem to remember too that there was an extra pro-Muggle version of The Wizard and the Hopping Pot that children would want to get rid of too? And definitely I love RP! I love RPing but I don't really have many opportunities to do so nowadays (at least back and forth) so it's quite enjoyable. Exactly what I meant with Harry, yes. But he's not a bookworm anyway.

Comment: @Bellatrix (Exception being a certain year six Potions book..)

Answer (score 46):

## Not children's stories, at least.

We find this dialogue in *The Deathly Hallows*:

> He felt as though he were sitting in an examination with a question he ought to have been able to answer in front of him, his brain slow and unresponsive. Was there something he had missed in the long talks with Dumbledore last year? Ought he to know what it all meant? Had Dumbledore expected him to understand?
>   “And as for this book,” said Hermione, “The Tales of Beedle the Bard . . . I’ve never even heard of them!”
>   “You’ve never heard of The Tales of Beedle the Bard?” said Ron incredulously. “You’re kidding, right?”
>
> Harry looked up, diverted. The circumstance of Ron having read a book that Hermione had not was unprecedented. Ron, however, looked bemused by their surprise.
>   “Oh come on! All the old kids’ stories are supposed to be Beedle’s, aren’t they? ‘The Fountain of Fair Fortune’ . . . ‘The Wizard and the Hopping Pot’ . . . ‘Babbitty Rabbitty and her Cackling Stump’ . . .”
>   “Excuse me?” said Hermione, giggling. “What was that last one?"
>   “Come off it!” said Ron, looking in disbelief from Harry to Hermione. “You must’ve heard of Babbitty Rabbitty —”
>   **“Ron, you know full well Harry and I were brought up by Muggles!” said Hermione. “We didn’t hear stories like that when we were little, we heard ‘Snow White and the Seven Dwarfs’ and ‘Cinderella’ —”
>
>   “What’s that, an illness?” asked Ron.**
>   “So these are children’s stories?” asked Hermione, bending again
>   over the runes.
>   “Yeah,” said Ron uncertainly, “I mean, that’s just what you hear,
>   you know, that all these old stories came from Beedle. I dunno what
>   they’re like in the original versions.”
>   <sub>*Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*, chapter 7: "The Will of Albus Dumbledore" (emphasis mine)</sub>

We can see from this that the Weaselys, at least, have never touched these, from which we can extrapolate that most Wizarding families won't have. And, extrapolating again, if they haven't heard of these fairy tales, it's highly unlikely that they'd have heard of other Muggle works.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76464/discussion-on-answer-by-mithrandir-do-wizards-know-of-great-literature-by-muggle).

Comment: And especially since Arthur Weasley is so fascinated by Muggles, he'd probably be one of the most likely wizarding parents to have read these stories to his children, and since he evidently didn't, I think it's fair to assume that no other wizarding children would've heard these stories either.

Comment: I think it's unclear if Ron have never actually heard about 'Cinderella' or is he just mocking Muggle culture.

Answer (score 10):

Wizard children get the ordinary Muggle-equivalent education up through about 5th or 6th grade. That's far enough to cover "The Three R's": Reading, 'riting, and 'rithmetic, to a reasonable if basic degree of proficiency in all of them. Beyond this, closest we see to a typical Muggle education is the number of essay-length and longer writing assignments.

One can understand why some of the other Muggle skills are neglected at this point. The further foundational math and science skills exist primarily to support engineering, and engineering in the magical world is in the main supplanted by magic. Want to build a bridge? Why learn geometry or materials science when you can just magic the bridge into place? Want to sell ball-point pens insted of quills? Why learn about inks or the physics of fluid dynamics when you can just magic the parts into place. Want to be a doctor? Why bother learning all that fuss about anatomy when you can just magically re-grow bones with a potion?

Which isn't to say the wizarding world neglects all science education. They just have a more-complete view of the natural world, and focus their time on (for their needs) the more practical areas of science. And so Potions replaces Chemistry, Charms replaces Physics, Herbology replaces Biology, Arithmancy replaces Calculus, and so on. You could make a good argument the wizard's school does a better job of teaching how the world actually works. It's not the wizards ignoring Muggle topics. They are at least aware the topics exist to some degree. Rather, it's the Muggles completely ignoring the magical aspects of the World.

Of course, that's not the whole of it. The wizarding world still functions on an economy. Wizard businesses still need to keep the books, and while basic arithmetic may be enough to get by in the highly-informal world shown to us by Ms Rowling, where everyone seems to know just about everyone else, the Muggle world teaches that those who know more math will be able to do *better* at business than those who don't, using data to do better at setting pricing, production levels, marketing, and all manner of other things.

We also only see the wizard's education system up through the High School level. We don't know what happens afterwards. For example, I'm sure Madam Pomfrey actually did spend quite a bit of time studying mundane anatomy before working in the Hogwarts hospital wing. If Ms Rowling ever really does want to extend the Harry Potter stories, I'm sure a 4-book series devoted to Harry's college years would be amazing.

But this question focuses specifically on literature, and this is the point that leaves me sad. I see no analogue in Hogwarts for literature at all. Forget Muggles; they don't seem to even study literature produced by wizards and witches.

Comment: The first book explains that wizards and witches are largely unskilled when it comes to science and logic, which is why Snape's challenge protecting the Sorceror's Stone was the most robust and it took an academic mind like Hermione's to get through it.

Comment: Rather than providing a more complete view of the natural world, magic largely invalidates science. They are opposites in a way. Except perhaps in the case of potions.

Answer (score 3):

**Do *you* know of great literature from other cultures?**

How well-versed are you on great Arabic poets? On ancient Chinese tales? On Indian fables? Spanish? German? Russian? Colombian? Ugandan?

In general, all cultures tend to focus on their own literary outputs, often lumping the rest into subjects such as "World Literature" or the like.

My personal experience attending schools in different countries was very bizarre in this respect, seeming as if each lived in a different world where entirely different things mattered, from lauded poets to transcendent historical episodes, each society and culture had its own perspective, and often ignored whatever was beyond their borders.

For most wizards, Muggle culture at large would be uninteresting simply out of basic human cultural inertia, and only those with an interest in Muggles would make that extra effort to read up on it.

Comment: There *are* works of literature that are known internationally. For example, Shakespeare, Tolstoy, and Steinbeck were part of the curriculum in Hungary when my mom was in school, and she remembers reading *Uncle Tom's Cabin* at some point in her childhood. (All of that in translation, naturally.) This wasn't "extra effort", it was just part of growing up and getting an education.

Comment: I agree with that notion, but my personal experience has shown that is not always the case. In one particular case I remember a World Literature teacher skipping most of the content of the actual textbook to focus only on anglo-saxon literature, but the again, in other countries there wasn't even a focus on World Literature at all.

Comment: @Martha I agree with Oskuro when it comes about curriculum in Spain. Shakespeare is not in the curriculum. In fact, it's not just that foreign languages literatures aren't in the curriculum: authors in Catalan or Basque aren't mentioned since the subject is just Spanish literature (meaning literature in Spanish). As far as I remember, Dickens, Zola or la Chanson de Roland were only mentioned in one sentence giving the international context of their equivalent literary movement in Spain. Not very different from how Wizards deal with Muggle literature.