# In Harry Potter, are we aware of any fairy-tales not in "The Tales of Beedle the Bard"?

Tags: harry-potter

In Deathly Hallows, Ron says:

> “Oh come on! **All** the old kids’ stories are supposed to be Beedle’s,
>   aren’t they? ‘The Fountain of Fair Fortune’ . . . ‘The Wizard and the
>   Hopping Pot’ . . . ‘Babbitty Rabbitty and her Cackling Stump’ . . .”

Is this true? Are there any non-Beedle fairy tales in Harry Potter?

Comment: The "all" in this quote refers to kids' stories rather than just fairy tales, right? Because there are a couple in [What do wizards read for fun?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/57097/98028): _A children's anthology of Monsters_ (anthology), _The Adventures of Martin Miggs, the Mad Muggle_ (comics).

Comment: @Jenayah All the "Old" kids stories. I doubt the monster anthology is old, Anyways, from the context, I'm sure Ron is exclusively refering to fairy tales.

Answer (score 6):

## Yes, there are wizarding fairy tales not written by Beedle the Bard.

The author of a reworked fairy tale collection for children, Beatrix Bloxam, took several old stories, including some of Beedle’s, and reworked them so they would be more suitable for children.

> “Mrs. Bloxam took **a variety of old stories, including several of Beedle’s**, and rewrote them according to her ideals, which she expressed as “filling the pure minds of our little angels with healthy, happy thoughts, keeping their sweet slumber free of wicked dreams, and protecting the precious flower of their innocence.” 
> <sub><sup>*- The Tales of Beedle the Bard*</sup></sub>

Bloxam reworked a variety of old stories, and though she did include some of Beedle’s in it, her collection of old stories wasn’t solely retellings of Beedle’s tales. This shows that there had to be other old stories that weren’t written by Beedle.

Comment: And don't forget about Aberforth's favorite bedtime story, "Grumble the Grubby Goat"